# Know if a molecule is viable with Python

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

I'm working with python and I'd like to know if someone knows a python module which is able to check if a molecule is **chemically viable** *(valence, connectivity constraints ...)*, or not. I know there is a lot of chemistry packages out there, but I didn't find any which does that.

Thanks,

Comment: And what is your "chemical viability" supposed to be?

Comment: Rules like valence constraint, connectivity constraint, etc...

Comment: Such a module probably doesn't exist because the inputs you are specifying aren't very clear. Are you specifying bonds? Should you have to specify bonds? What if you include an extreme angle? What counts as extreme? What about non-classical bonds? What about multiple valency? And so on...

Comment: @Robin That "etc." of yours is a tiny door with a really big hairy monster behind it. All those who tried to develop such modules were devoured by this monster, hence we're out of luck.

Comment: Well, I have a list of reactants and edits (bonds that will be created/destroyed). I want to know what kind of products are feasible from these reactants/edits. I don't expect a tool with an exhaustive list of these rules but something which could filter out most absurd reactions (ie. prevent a C from having 5 bonds).

Comment: @RobinFourcade I think your last comment is highly instructive in this discussion. Why can't carbon have 5 bonds? $\ce{CH5+}$ [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanium) is a known, albeit highly reactive, species.

Comment: You could program your own, and then improve it with time. Start with defining your molecule (atoms list and bonds list). Then, for each one, run a set of constraints (for example "if atom is carbon, count bonds, must be four else molecule is invalid). Then improve your constraints (for example you may exclude rare scenarios like carbon double bonds with anything else than carbon, oxygen, nitrogen, etc.)